# Adding weights to all edges of graph - change in spanning tree and shortest paths

Tags: algorithm, graph

> (a) Let T be a minimum spanning tree of a weighted graph G. Construct
>   a new graph G by adding a weight of k to every edge of G. Do the edges
>   of T form a minimum spanning tree of G. Prove the statement or give a
>   counterexample.
>
> (b) Let P = {s, . . . , t} describe a shortest weighted path between
>   vertices s and t of a weighted graph G. Construct a new graph G by
>   adding a weight of k to every edge of G. Does P describe a shortest
>   path from s to t in G. Prove the statement or give a counterexample.

My solution:

a) Edges of T still form minimum spanning tree of G, since all edge weights are increased by same amount.

b) P still describes shortest path from s to t in G (same reason)

Can someone please verify the answers?

Comment: "viewed 3317 times"... I don't get how this is "unlikely to help any future visitors"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although I don't think SO is the best place for your question, your answer to question B is definitely wrong.

Consider a graph with 3 vertices (A,B,C), with the following edges:

```
A-B = 1
A-C = 0
C-B = 0
```

The shortest weighted path between A and B is A-C-B. If you add 2 to all the weights, your shortest path becomes A-B.

(Sorry, missed the first part of the question, there is an answer for that already by now. The reason why `a` is correct but `b` is wrong is that spanning trees always contain exactly `n-1` edges, while the number of edges in a shortest weighted path may vary.)

Answer (score 4):

a) Correct. Because cost of every MST increases by (n-1)*k.

b) Wrong. Consider graph with 3 vertices and edges:
1-2: 3
2-3: 3
1-3: 10
Now shortest path from 1 do 3 goes through 2.
Now add 10 to cost if every edge. Now the shortest path goes directly from 1 to 3.